# Complex Projective Line

Tags: hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics

How can I go about showing that a collection of all states is the complex projective line $CP^1$?

All I understand at the moment is that an element in $CP^1$ is of the form $\lambda(\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle) \: for \: \lambda \in C$.

Answer (score 1):

The states, if I understand you correctly, are parametrized by the pairs of complex numbers $(\alpha, \beta)$ up to non-zero scalar. But that is exactly $\mathbb{C}P^1$ by definition. (see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space))

Comment: I am not sure I understand completely. The article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere#As_the_complex_projective_line talks about the relationship $(\alpha,\beta)=(\lambda\alpha,\lambda\beta)=\lambda(\alpha,\beta)$?

Comment: yes, it does. the set of all lines is exactly the set of all vectors up to proportionality (just map any vector to the line passing through it)